# Mysql query IN or NOT IN faster?

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb

I have two simple queries below:

```
SELECT * from table_name where status IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
SELECT * from table_name where status NOT IN (5, 6)
```

The possible value of status is 0 to 6, and column status is indexed.

In the queries above, WHERE IN has 5 statuses, but WHERE NOT IN only has 2 statuses. I don't have much data in my DB so the query speed does not have any different.

But what if the data is big, which query will be faster?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Add 10.000.000 values. Compare the updated queries, both explain plans and actual execution time. Also find alternative queries, returning the same result. Quite interesting actually.

Comment: The process of resolving an index reads the index itself sequentially and creates a list of areas in the data table to look.  If your values are limited to 0-6 then there is no difference,  performance-wise.

Comment: @VanTho I don't think this is an inherently bad question. I've seen optimizers get flummoxed by things that appear easy and seen them do borderline magic to come up with the same plan for queries written quite differently. jarlh is on the money though. If performance is going to be a factor, approach it like performance testing and manufacture data that will mimic production stress.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer it might actually make a difference *assuming* the first 4 values are rare (have high discriminatory power). Dunno about mysql but postgres is unable to invert `NOT IN` queries, so a `NOT IN` will almost never be able to use an index, whereas the opposite `IN` might.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer That's because indexes are used depending on statistics, IME for postgres they're ignored if the value(s) being looked up are above ~10%, and most used if under ~1%. So the `NOT IN` might be able to use the index to exclude 5 and 6 if they're under 10% of the table combined, however that means retrieving >90% of the table so it'll just go with a full scan. For the `IN` however it will probably perform an index scan if the values combined tally up under 10% of total the planner will likely do a bitmap heap scan, under 1% it'll almost certainly do an index scan.

Comment: I will try to create 10m records and test it later. Arcording to many comments here, WHERE IN should faster than WHERE NOT IN. I believe that this question may help someone in the future when choosing the best query

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion,

- The WHERE `IN` query is likely to be faster, especially if the status column is indexed. This is because the `IN` condition with a list of values can take advantage of the index to quickly locate the matching rows. On the other hand, the `NOT IN` condition, with fewer values, may still benefit from the index but might involve scanning a larger portion of it.
- If your dataset is large, and the status column is indexed, prefer the `WHERE IN` query for better performance.

Comment: Yeah I think so too, and many comments in this question have the same idea

Answer (score 1):

If the status column has only 7 values (0 to 6), then the index will not be used at all, since the cardinality is too low. The optimizer will perform a table scan (Even the index file will not be scanned, since you select more columns than the status column).

Assuming a balanced distribution of status values, the NOT IN clause will be faster since it has a smaller range: max 2 different values have to be checked, while with IN clause max. 5 different values have to be checked.

```
select benchmark(10000000, floor(rand() * 7) in (0,1,2,3,4));
0.423 sec

select benchmark(10000000, floor(rand() * 7) not in (5,6));
0.363 sec
```

Comment: My DB is MySql, the query where not in took 0.515s, where in took 0.651s, when I try again with same values, IN and NOT IN return almost same result (~0.65s)

Comment: But I think the index will be used, because I've tried with an big database and the speed is faster

Comment: You can check if Index will be used by using EXPLAIN SELECT ..

Answer (score -1):

The clauses IN and NOT IN are both performance intensive as the result depends on the size of the datasets used in operation. However an optimised approach depends on using JOIN operator or EXISTS or NOT EXISTS subqueries and indexing the column will give signficant improvement in performance.